# Linux kernel modules.builtin in build directory does not match kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I am building a linux kernel in a standard way:

```
make mrproper
make defconfig
make
```

At the end of the build, there is a file modules.builtin in the top build directory.

When I boot to the kernel on my board, and inspect /lib/modules//modules.builtin, the modules do not match with the modules.builtin file in my build directory.

Is this expected? Do I need to do

```
make modules
```

to get the two modules.builtin files to match?

Answer (score 1):

You miss installation step after the build:

```sh
make modules_install # Copy modules into their final location, call 'depmod'
make install # Install kernel core
```

Comment: Thankyou. In make modules_install, where should I set the final destination so that the modules are packaged into the kernel image? I should say that I'm building the kernel for an embedded board.

Comment: It is `make install` who cares about kernel image. Usually it does that without additional information from the user.

Comment: Sorry, see my edited response - I'm building for an embedded system, so I don't want to install the modules to /lib/modules/<version>/ on my build host system.

Comment: So you should **build** the kernel for your embedded system. Usually, it means setting appropriate `ARCH` and `CROSS_COMPILE` variables in `make` invocation. Just google for "kernel cross-compiling".

Comment: Yes, I can do the build part fine. The problem is that not all the modules I build are present when I boot the kernel, i.e.

    /lib/modules/<version>/modules.builtin (on embedded)

does not match

    /home/user/kernelbuild/modules.builtin (on build host)

Comment: You ask `where should I set the final destination so that the modules are packaged into the kernel image?`, but in case of *cross-compiling* there is **deployment** step, when compiled kernel (with modules) goes into the target machine. And *deployment* step is mainly target-specific: you choose sysroot directory, you choose the way, how files from this directory are copied into target, and so on. But you doesn't provide any information about that. How can we ask you question without knowledge about your case?

Comment: Ok, sounds like I need to do some reading. Thanks for your help.